# How change language depending on the url params using the i18n-2 module

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, internationalization, middleware

I'm going crazy!

Since yesterday I am trying to set the [i18n-2](https://github.com/jeresig/i18n-node-2) module, but could not make the change of language, can anyone help me?

This node.js module have a poor documentation, want don't have examples of how to change the language using /:params

So i am trying like this:

// Configurations:

```
I18n.expressBind(app, {
    locales: ['en', 'pt'],
    cookieName: 'locale'
});
```

And this is how i am trying to change the language depending on the /:locale

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    req.i18n.setLocale(req.params.locale);
    next();
});

app.get('/:locale', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.i18n.__("My Site Title"));
});
```

And i have two files in the locale folder, 'pt.json' - portuguese, and 'en.json' - english.

PT:

```
{
    "My Site Title": "Titulo",
}
```

EN:

```
{
    "My Site Title": "My Title",
}
```

But is not working AT ALL... even if i try access site.com/pt, the en json will be loaded.

What i am doing wrong here?

Comment: Try `req.i18n.setLocaleFromCookie();` instead of `req.i18n.setLocale(req.params.locale);` . `And i have two files in the locale folder` - you mean `locales`?

Comment: yes, i mean locales @Valijon, the req.i18n.setLocaleFromCookie(); doesn't work.. i think notting is working, cause if i change the console.log(req.i18n.__("My Site Title")); to console.log(req.i18n.__("other thing"));, the other thing will be printed.. =(..

Comment: https://ide.c9.io/celicoo/test the code is here..

Comment: I dont have `user` in c9.io. Set `devMode = true` to debug what is going wrong. By the way, try to force by changing locale ´req.i18n.setLocale(pt')´

Comment: i figure out the problem, i don't need create the translate files, i just need put in the ejs __("Some text"), them the module will generate the file, them i need change the text there.. very difficult to figure out, poor documentation..